# VueJS: Passing Vuex property value from parent to child component and avoid "undefined"

Tags: vuex

I'm passing an argument from a parent component using Vuex property. However, when the component is loaded, the Vuex property is still `undefined`, generating the following error message:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of
>   undefined"

I'm passing the property like this:

```
<card
    :image="$store.state.company.card_img[0].url"
></card>
```

It works fine but I'd like to know how to do it the right way to avoid the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use computed properties to check available data:

```
computed: {
  imageUrl: function() {
    if (this.$store.state.company && this.$store.state.company.card_img && this.$store.state.company.card_img.length > 0) {
      return this.$store.state.company.card_img[0].url
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

and in template

```
<card
    :image="imageUrl"
></card>
```

Another methods is using [vuex getters](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html)

Comment: Thanks, but with this code, my component doesn't show anymore and I get the following error message: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'card_img' of undefined".

Comment: Thanks! Now, it works :-) Just add `this.` to the returned property and this answer will be perfect.

Comment: Thanks! Updated my answer!